# Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox displays artifacts

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, tearing

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox 6.1.36 r152435 (Qt5.6.2) for months and after installing latest updates yesterday (apt-get upgrade) I'm seeing screen tearing and some strange artifacts on my screen. It's laggy and less responsive than before the upgrades. I have latest guest additions installed and all possible upgrades on my host machine. I always had 3D acceleration disabled.

Host: i7-12700KF, MSI MAG Z690 Tomahawk, RTX 3070 Ti, 32 GB RAM, Windows 10 Pro

I've upgraded VirtualBox to 6.1.46 and installed new guest additions, but it's still the same.

This is how it looks when moving any window.

[image: this is how it looks like when moving any window]